# How to destroy my tkinter label after multiple button click?

Tags: tkinter

I am working an application where I had a **CALB** button and according to application when I press **CALB** button 1st a Label created and show **range_H** value and if I press **CALB** button 2nd time It will show **off_set** value.
As per my requirement ,the label should be destroyed after **ENTR** key press.
My issue is It is working with single **CALB** click but not destroyed after 2nd click of **CALB** button click.
Here is my code

```
import os
import tkinter as tk

Dsel = 0
cal_c = 0
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x240")
range_High = tk.IntVar()
offset = tk.IntVar()
Dsell = tk.IntVar()
range_H = 32767
off_set = 0

file=open("D:\data/file_log.txt","w")
if os.stat("D:\data/file_log.txt").st_size==0:
    file.write("rangeHigh,offset,\n")
file.write(str(range_H)+','+str(off_set))
file.flush()

def cal():
    global range_High,Dsel,cal_c
    cal_c = cal_c + 1
    root.rangeLabel = tk.Label(root, textvariable=range_High)
    root.rangeLabel.grid(row=0)
    root.DLbl = tk.Label(root,textvariable=Dsell)
    root.DLbl.grid(row=0,column=1)
    if cal_c == 1:
        range_High.set(range_H)
    elif cal_c == 2:
        range_High.set(off_set)
    Dsell.set(Dsel)
   

def enter():
    global range_High
    file=open("D:\data/file_log.txt","w")
    if os.stat("D:\data/file_log.txt").st_size==0:
        file.write("rangeHigh,offset,\n")
    file.write(str(range_H) + ',' + str(off_set))
    file.flush()
    root.rangeLabel.destroy()
    root.DLbl.destroy()
def inc():
    
    #increment logic
    pass
def dec():
    
    #decrement logic
    pass

def digSelect():
    global Dsel
    Dsel = Dsel+1
    if Dsel > 5:
        Dsel = 0
    Dsell.set(Dsel)



root.Bt1=tk.Button(root,text="calb",bg="red",command=cal)
root.Bt1.pack()
root.Bt1.place(x=200,y=50)
root.Bt2=tk.Button(root,text="entr",bg="red",command=enter)
root.Bt2.pack()
root.Bt2.place(x=200,y=80)
root.Bt3=tk.Button(root,text="incr",bg="red",fg="white",command=inc)
root.Bt3.pack()
root.Bt3.place(x=200,y=110)
root.Bt4=tk.Button(root,text="decr",bg="red",fg="white",command=dec)
root.Bt4.pack()
root.Bt4.place(x=200,y=140)
root.Bt5=tk.Button(root,text="digt",bg="red",fg="white",command=digSelect)
root.Bt5.pack()
root.Bt5.place(x=200,y=170)


root.mainloop()
```

Thank you

Comment: Actually you have created `root.rangeLabel` and `root.DLbl` twice when `calb` button is clicked twice.  Only the last instance of them are deleted when `entr` button is clicked.  You can move the creation of the two labels inside `if cal_c == 1` block.

Comment: @acw1668, then inside `if cal_c == 2` block i have to create new label to show offset value?

Comment: Don't need as you have updated the IntVar `range_High` which is linked to `root.rangeLabel`.

Comment: @acw1668, Now my application flow became 1st click **Calb** button and adjust `range_H` value and press **entr** to save and again to adjust `off_set` value I have to follow same procedure.